# Limit Points and Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

T or F questions:

1). If $p$ is a limit point of $M$, then $p$ is in $M$.

I know this is false because $M$ can be the open interval $M$ = $(a,b)$ and $p$ not be in it, and it be a limit point.

2). The range of the sequence can have exactly two points in it.

I'm pretty sure this is true. I'm not sure how to explain this. Would the sequence $(-1)^n$ work?

3). A sequence cannot converge to a point that is not in the range of the sequence.

I'm guessing this is false? Could someone help me find a few examples of a sequence where this statement is false?

4). If a set is not open, it must be closed.

I know this false because they're compliments of each other, but that doesn't mean it has to be one or the other. Right? Can someone give me a few examples of a set that is not open or closed please?

Comment: What do you mean in (2)?  Is "*the* sequence" given, or this is an assertion on *all* sequences?
(3) Consider $(1/n)_n$ converging to $0$

Comment: All sequences .And thank you!

Comment: So you mean "the range of *all* sequence*s* can have exactly two points in it"?  A constant "sequence" immediately comes into my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Edited based on comments

1. done, you're correct
2. done, your sequence works
3. Consider the sequence $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$. The limit 0 is not in the range
4. Consider the interval $[1,2)\subset \mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology

Comment: Answers like these might confuse who is asking for help. When you say that $[1,2)$ is neither open nor closed you should specify which topological space you are working in. The set $[1,2)$ is open in $[1,2]$ endowed with the induced topology of $\mathbb{R}$, thought of as a topological space with the standard topology. Further, $1/n$ is not a sequence - $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}}$ with $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ is the sequence you mean.